# Yii- client side validation is not working on CActiveForm

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, yii, client-side-validation

I've an active form in my application. But the client side validation is not working. The code of the form are as shown below:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'application-data-student-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
    'clientOptions'=>array('onSubmit'=>true),
    'htmlOptions'=>array(
        'enctype'=>'multipart/form-data',
        'role'=>'form',
        'class'=>'form-horizontal'
    ),
)); ?>
```

*I've used bootstrap 3 in my project.* Any idea or solution will be highly appreciated from anybody . . .

Comment: Can you show full view code, model `rules` method and controller action code?

Comment: The controller and models are generated by crud. so, I think there are no problem on those. I just want to validate for required fields.

Comment: And what about view (how you generate your form fields)?

Comment: The form fields are also generated by crud. And I'm using bootstrap in my project. Does it have affect the default js files?

Comment: Which extension (for bootstrap) do you use?

Comment: Make sure all the js files required for validation(jquery.yiiactiveform.js) is there on the page and there is no conflicts too!! Inspect with a firebug!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally resolved the problem. I'm posting this so that it may help someone with the same problem.

The problem was caused because jquery.js was not loaded properly in the application. The map file was missing that is required by the jquery.js. So I downloaded the latest jquery 2.1.1.min.js & respective map file from [[http://jquery.com/download/]](http://jquery.com/download/%5d) and loaded them in the main layout. Now the validation is finally working.

Hope this workaround will help someone with same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try add in model action something like this:

```
if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest){
    echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

or uncoment this line

```
// Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
// $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
```

Comment: I'm not using the ajax validation. Hence the above approach might not be the reason. . .